# entry requirements and entrance requirements

Tags: vocabulary

**Are there any differences between ENTRY requirements and ENTRANCE requirements? Is it interchangeable?
In this sentence below, which one do you think is more suitable or both of them are acceptable?**

*In fact, applying to study abroad could even work to your advantage. You might encounter lower _________ requirements, or you could benefit from a longer application window.*

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: In the US many people would tend to interpret "entry requirements" as immigration restrictions, whereas "entrance requirements" is idiomatic for the standard associated with admission to a school.

Comment: I tend to agree with Hot Licks, and I suspect his reason for Posting a Comment  is the same as mine: the work of justifying an Answer, however valid, isn't warranted.

Further, in my view your Question and Example might leave as many queries after resolving "entry/entrance".

Don't you think this would find better help in a writing forum?